# Connectivity between Control-M and Power BI

Tags: connection, powerbi, scheduler, control-m

Does any one have any idea about connectivity between Control-M and Power BI ?

I want to achive event based scheduling for Power BI Reports(Paginated Reports).

We are trying to implement even based scheduling in our project. Currenly , In existing architechture they are using control M for scheduling the crystal reports. Is there any other way ? Can we integrate Control M and Powerbi reports using some API ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Control-M supports CLI, API, the whole shooting match. There is a module (part of the standard Control-M package) called Application Integrator (confusingly referred to as AI) which allows people to create bespoke integrations and (if they wish) share them via a community hub.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [PowerBI API to refresh data](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/) up to 8 times a day on Pro or 48 times a day on Premium. You could also use direct query to provide the report data on the fly.

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/refreshes
```

Once the refresh completes you can mail out a link to the report and your users will get the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Control-M supports CLI, API, the whole shooting match. There is a module (part of the standard Control-M package) called Application Integrator (confusingly referred to as AI) which allows people to create bespoke integrations and (if they wish) share them via a community hub. A BMC staff member has created an integration for Power BI and it can be downloaded here - https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-125437 with a guide here (including the author's email - https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-125436

Answer (score 0):

Control-M has a fully supported integration with Power BI's SaaS version. Docs can be found here: https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ctm_integrations/control-m-for-power-bi-1087134531.html